# Convert object address to string

Tags: javascript, arcgis

In my application when you single-click a point on the map it returns the address. Example:

```
locator.on("location-to-address-complete", function(evt) {
if (evt.address.address) {
      var address = evt.address.address;
      var location = webMercatorUtils.geographicToWebMercator(evt.address.location);
      console.log(address)
    }
});
```

console displays:

```
Object {Address: "1029 W Cermak Rd", Neighborhood: null, City: "Chicago", Subregion: null, Region: "Illinois"…}
```

Is there a way to convert the address to a string. Basically I just want:
1029 W Cermak Rd., Chicago, Illinois.

Thank you.

Comment: so build the string from the object... `console.log(address.Address + ", " + address.City + " " + address.Region)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no generic way to do this. You just need to concatenate the fields you're interested in. You can use [`filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) to filter out the nil/empty fields, and then `join` the results.

```
var address = evt.address.address;

addressString = [
  address.Address,
  address.Neighborhood,
  address.City,
  address.Region,
  address.Subregion,
].filter(function (val) { return val }).join(", ");
```

Comment: You need to remove null values (if they are not known)

Comment: @soktinpk True, fixed

Comment: This leaves a beginning comma to start the address: , 1029 Cermak Rd, Chicago, Illinois

Comment: @Andrew Ah, true. See update. I'm not sure what started me down the `reduce` route, but `filter` is the correct method to use.